# Установка puppy linux на live флешку с arch

Tags: linux, archlinux

Есть флешка на которой размещен образ арча и syslinux (записывал с помощью dd).

Можно ли поставить на нее рядом puppy как полноценную ос?

Если да то как это можно сделать?

Comment: Скопировав разделы puppy (за исключением boot) и поправив конфигурацию GRUB это возможно. С последним, возможно, удастся справиться используя утилиты GRUB.
На практике это может занять ни один час

Comment: @Gedweb то есть легче отформатировать флешку и идти протоптанной дорогой?

Comment: @melancholiac, по моему скромному мнению на ваши вопросы (их два: «можно ли?» и «как?») невозможно дать исчерпывающие ответы **разумных** размеров.

Comment: кстати, [вот (**лишь частичный**) ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544936/178576) на первый ваш вопрос.