# Как сохранить файлы при использовании live-usb?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Как сделать так, чтобы при перезагрузке "Xubuntu" на флешке оставались файлы.

Сейчас после того, как я загружусь, с флешки пропадают файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хм... насколько понял загружаешься в лайв-режиме.... единственное что могу посоветовать разбить флешку на два раздела и второй использовать для личных файлов и конфигов

Comment: флешка вот не разбивается "**Acronis-ом 12**" может что посоветуешь?

Comment: GParted  или его аналоги

Comment: http://www.lubuntu.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=237 может это подойдёт?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Сейчас после того, как я загружусь, с флешки пропадают файлы.

если быть точным, то «пропадают» файлы в момент завершения работы системы. потому что хранятся они (при использовании live-образов) в оперативной памяти.

если на съёмном блочном устройстве, где записан образ (на т.н. «флэшке») есть свободное пространство и удастся создать на нём дополнительный раздел, то, создав на этом разделе файловую систему, вы сможете использовать её для сохранения файлов.

проделать все эти операции можно, например, загрузившись прямо с этого носителя с помощью программы [*gparted*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted), которая, скорее всего, присутствует в записанном вами образе.

удастся ли создать раздел, зависит целиком и полностью от того:

- как именно был сформирован образ
- каким именно образом вы его записали на блочное устройство

---

если создать раздел не удастся, то для хранения файлов можно, например, использовать другое съёмное блочное устройство (т.н. «флэшку»).